# storing line numbers of expressions with boost.spirit 2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I am planning on doing a script transformation utility (for extended diagnostic information) using Boost.Spirit 2.

While there is support for line information etc. for parsing errors, how i can store line numbers for successfully parsed expressions with Qi?

Comment: Hey gf I have a question open related to spirit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183067/boostspirit-grammar-for-unsorted-schema perhaps you know some way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the mailing list, *Spirit.Classic* [positional iterators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/classic/doc/position_iterator.html) can also be used with *Spirit 2*.
There is also an article on an [iter_pos-parser](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/creating-your-own-parser-component-for-spirit-qi) on the *Spirit*-blog.

<sub>I will update when i had time to test.</sub>

Comment: Quoting Joel Guzman from that article: _`..., if you don’t want to do any “Metacthulhu”, then this is the wrong article for you`_ / ... _`this is an advanced topic as people don’t normally want to extend Spirit and write their own components`_.

Answer (score 2):

I realize I noticed the question late, but let me add this anyway. I wrote a sample of an INI file parser in another answer:

- [Cross-platform way to get line number of an INI file where given option was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427)

This uses a 'simple' semantic action with `line_pos_iterator`.

Here is the fruit of my labour: https://gist.github.com/1425972

- When `POSITIONINFO == 0`

  - input is streaming
  - output is raw strings (well, `map<string, map<string, string> >` for the sections)
- When `POSITIONINFO == 1`

  - input is buffered
  - output is `textnode_t`:

    ```
    struct textnode_t {
        int sline, eline, scol, ecol;
        string_t text;
    };
    ```

    This means that the resulting `map<textnode_t, map<textnode_t, textnode_t> >` is able to report exactly what (line,col) start and end points mark the individual text nodes.

***Here is a reduced demo. For full description and extensive test cases see [the original anser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427) or the code at [github](https://gist.github.com/1425972)***

### Demo Input

```
[Cat1]
name1=100 #skipped

name2=200 \#not \\skipped
name3=   dhfj dhjgfd
```

### Demo Output (POSITIONINFO == 0)

```
Parse success!
[Cat1]
name1 = 100 
name2 = 200 \#not \\skipped
name3 = dhfj dhjgfd
```

### Demo Output (POSITIONINFO == 1)

```
Parse success!
[[L:1,C2 .. L1,C6:Cat1]]
[L:2,C2 .. L2,C7:name1] = [L:2,C8 .. L2,C12:100 ]
[L:6,C2 .. L6,C7:name2] = [L:6,C8 .. L6,C27:200 \#not \\skipped]
[L:7,C2 .. L7,C7:name3] = [L:7,C11 .. L7,C22:dhfj dhjgfd]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/tracking-the-input-position-while-parsing/) is another useful article that explains how to use the exception that the `phrase_parse` function throws.

The article describes how to get error messages like this:

```
Exception: parse error at file STDIN line 1 column 10
'123,42.0,a,1.4'
          ^- here
```

Comment: You're bit late to the party. Also, your suggestion doesn't answer the question as it deals only with exceptions (specificly, `expectation_failure`). I posted **[an example](https://gist.github.com/1425972)** of how to use Spirit Qi to parse into nodes which store the source location _as well as_ the parsed value in **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8365427/85371)** with extensive tests/samples.