# boost::Spirit Grammar for unsorted schema

Tags: c++, parsing, grammar, boost-spirit, recursive-descent

I have a section of a schema for a model that I need to parse. Lets say it looks like the following.

```
{
  type = "Standard";
  hostname="x.y.z";
  port="123";
}
```

The properties are:

1. The elements may appear unordered.
2. All elements that are part of the schema must appear, and no other.
3. All of the elements' synthesised attributes go into a struct.
4. (optional) The schema might in the future depend on the type field -- i.e., different fields based on type -- however I am not concerned about this at the moment.

Comment: "Only the desired elements may appear (specified by type-names)": the value of the `type` key dictates what other keys are valid in the section?

Comment: @somebody : not in this case -- but it's a good point, and I might benefit from any such insights -- after all type="erlang" might require more than the hostname and port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Spirit forums, the following is the answer.

> You might want to have a look at the
>   permutation parser:
>
> ```
> a ^ b ^ c
> ```
>
> Which matches a or b or c (or a
>   combination thereof) in any sequence.

If the objective is to parse into a struct, than the best way to test weather all essential members have been initialized, the struct members should be wrapped with `boost::optional<>` The attribute presence may then be easily tested post-parsing during run-time.