# Using Spirit qi::success callbacks to set fields after a rule match

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to use `qi::on_success` callback ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51254774/2987773)) to set a field when a rule is matched. The code below is slightly adapted from this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62970956/2987773) though my slight changes to the rules/ast class has made it no to recognize `_rule_name`. My intention is commented in the code below. I want to set the field `term_type` to `TermType::literal` if the `_literal` rule is matched or to `Term::rule_name` if `_rule_name` rule is matched.

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    enum class TermType {
        literal,
        rule_name
    };


    struct Term {
        std::string data;
        TermType term_type;
    };

    using List = std::list<Term>;
    using Expression = std::list<List>;

    struct Rule {
        Term name; // lhs
        Expression rhs;
    };

    using Syntax = std::list<Rule>;
}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Term, data)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Rule, name, rhs)

namespace Parser {
    template<typename Iterator>
    struct BNF : qi::grammar<Iterator, Ast::Syntax()> {
        BNF() : BNF::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi;
            _blank = blank;
            _skipper = blank | (eol >> !skip(_blank.alias())[_rule]);
            start = skip(_skipper.alias())[_rule % +eol];

            _rule = _rule_name >> "::=" >> _expression;
            _expression = _list % '|';
            _list = +(_literal | _rule_name);
            _literal = '"' >> *(_character - '"') >> '"'
                    | "'" >> *(_character - "'") >> "'";
            _character = alnum | char_("\"'| !#$%&()*+,./:;>=<?@]\\^_`{}~[-");
            _rule_name = '<' >> (alpha >> *(alnum | char_('-'))) >> '>';

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                    (_rule)(_expression)(_list)(_literal)
                            (_character)
                            (_rule_name))
        }

        /*qi::on_success(_term, setTermTypeHandler());

        setTermTypeHandler(){
             if term is literal
                term.symbol_type = TermType::literal
            else
                term.term_type = TermType::rule_name
        }
        */

    private:
        using Skipper = qi::rule<Iterator>;
        Skipper _skipper, _blank;

        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Syntax()> start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Rule(), Skipper> _rule;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Expression(), Skipper> _expression;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::List(), Skipper> _list;
        // lexemes
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Term()> _literal;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Term()> _rule_name;
        //  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()>     _literal;
        qi::rule<Iterator, char()> _character;
    };
}

int main() {
    Parser::BNF<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;

    std::string const input = R"(<code>   ::=  <letter><digit> | <letter><digit><code>
<letter> ::= "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"
           | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i"
<digit>  ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" |
             "4"
    )";

    auto it = input.begin(), itEnd = input.end();

    Ast::Syntax syntax;
    if (parse(it, itEnd, parser, syntax)) {
        for (auto &rule : syntax) {
            std::cout << rule.name.data << " ::= ";
            std::string sep;
            for (auto &list : rule.rhs) {
                std::cout << sep;
                for (auto &term: list) { std::cout << term.data; }
                sep = " | ";
            };
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }

    if (it != itEnd)
        std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(it, itEnd)) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that the whole endeavour is to remove the `variant` `Term` and replace it with your own discriminated struct?

Comment: @sehe yes. I could have used two different structs but I don't think that is good design.

Comment: I dunno. `std::variant` is a standard library vocabulary type, I'd say `variant<Name, Literal>` is the de-facto good design. I'll wriet a sample side-by-side later tonight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your struct `Term` has become a discriminated union of Name/Literal emulated by a tuple (std::string, TermType) I would make it so that both `_literal` and `_rule_name` just create a string, and append the TermType with `qi::attr`.

So,

```
struct Term {
    std::string data;
    TermType term_type;
};
```

Adapting both members

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Term, data, term_type)
```

Declaring relevant rules:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Term()>   _term;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> _literal;
qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> _rule_name;
```

which are initialized as

```
_list       = +_term;
_term       = _literal >> attr(Ast::TermType::literal)
            | _rule_name >> attr(Ast::TermType::rule_name);
_literal    = '"' >> *(_character - '"') >> '"'
            | "'" >> *(_character - "'") >> "'";

_character = alnum | char_("\"'| !#$%&()*+,./:;>=<?@]\\^_`{}~[-");
_rule_name = '<' >> (alpha >> *(alnum | char_('-'))) >> '>';
```

This keeps with my creed that you should try to avoid semantic actions ([Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)) and keeps the complexity to a minimum.

### `on_success`

I think the idea to use `on_success` was ill-advised here because it works well for non-context-dependent actions (like binding source location to each AST node, regardless of the type).

In this case you *explicitly* want to add *different* information (the variant discrimator), so you're better served injecting that into the particular branch of the parser expression it applies to.

### Sidenotes?

You seem to have complicated things for yourself by promoting the type of
`Rule::name` to `Term` (instead of `std::string`, where it used to be `Name`).

The name of a rule cannot be any other literal, so I'd suggest

1. either reverting it down to `std::string` (stripping it from the extra type
   info that `Name` had)

   ```
   struct Rule {
       std::string name; // lhs 
       Expression rhs;
   };
   ```
2. **or** making `_rule_name` synthesize into `Term` directly (including the
   `TermType` into its rule) https://godbolt.org/z/Kbb9dP
3. **or** Keeping the best of both worlds where `Term` has a conversion
   constructor that takes `Name`:

   ```
   explicit Term(Name other)
       : data(std::move(other))
       , term_type(TermType::rule_name)
   { }
   ```

### Literate Programming with ADTs

Note that the loss of the `Name` literate type was NOT without cost, because
the [output became very wrong](https://godbolt.org/z/Kbb9dP). I'd suggest the
last approach (bullet 3. above) adding a custom `operator<<` for your own variant emulation:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Term const& term) {
    switch(term.term_type) {
        case TermType::rule_name: return os << Name(term.data);
        case TermType::literal:   return os << std::quoted(term.data);
        default:                  return os << "?";
    }
}
```

Now you can enjoy your own variant type and correct output again:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dre6b3)**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    struct Name : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
        explicit Name(std::string s) : std::string(std::move(s)) {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Name const& n) {
            return os << '<' << n.c_str() << '>';
        }
    };

    enum class TermType { literal, rule_name };

    struct Term {
        std::string data;
        TermType term_type;

        Term() = default;
        explicit Term(Name other)
            : data(std::move(other))
            , term_type(TermType::rule_name)
        { }

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Term const& term) {
            switch(term.term_type) {
                case TermType::rule_name: return os << Name(term.data);
                case TermType::literal:   return os << std::quoted(term.data);
                default:                  return os << "?";
            }
        }
    };

    using List = std::list<Term>;
    using Expression = std::list<List>;

    struct Rule {
        Name name; // lhs
        Expression rhs;
    };

    using Syntax = std::list<Rule>;
}
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Term, data, term_type)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::Rule, name, rhs)

namespace Parser {
    template <typename Iterator>
    struct BNF : qi::grammar<Iterator, Ast::Syntax()> {
        BNF()
            : BNF::base_type(start)
        {
            using namespace qi;
            // clang-format off
            _blank      = blank;
            _skipper    = blank | (eol >> !skip(_blank.alias()) [ _rule ]);
            start       = skip(_skipper.alias()) [ _rule % +eol ];

            _rule       = _rule_name >> "::=" >> _expression;
            _expression = _list % '|';
            _list       = +_term;
            _term       = _literal >> attr(Ast::TermType::literal)
                        | _rule_name;
            _literal    = '"' >> *(_character - '"') >> '"'
                        | "'" >> *(_character - "'") >> "'";

            _character = alnum | char_("\"'| !#$%&()*+,./:;>=<?@]\\^_`{}~[-");
            _rule_name = '<' >> qi::raw[ (alpha >> *(alnum | char_('-'))) ] >> '>';

            // clang-format on
            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (_rule)(_expression)(_list)(_literal)(_character)(_rule_name))
        }

      private:
        using Skipper = qi::rule<Iterator>;
        Skipper _skipper, _blank;

        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Syntax()>     start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Rule(),       Skipper> _rule;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Expression(), Skipper> _expression;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::List(),       Skipper> _list;
        // lexemes
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Term()>   _term;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> _literal;
        qi::rule<Iterator, Ast::Name()>   _rule_name;
        qi::rule<Iterator, char()>        _character;
    };
}

int main() {
    Parser::BNF<std::string::const_iterator> const parser;

    std::string const input = R"(<code>   ::=  <letter><digit> | <letter><digit><code>
<letter> ::= "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e"
           | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i"
<digit>  ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" |
             "4"
    )";

    auto it = input.begin(), itEnd = input.end();

    Ast::Syntax syntax;
    if (parse(it, itEnd, parser, syntax)) {
        for (auto &rule : syntax) {
            std::cout << rule.name << " ::= ";
            std::string sep;
            for (auto &list : rule.rhs) {
                std::cout << std::exchange(sep, " | ");
                for (auto &term: list) { std::cout << term; }
            };
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed\n";
    }

    if (it != itEnd)
        std::cout << "Remaining: " << std::quoted(std::string(it, itEnd)) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
<code> ::= <letter><digit> | <letter><digit><code>
<letter> ::= "a" | "b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "g" | "h" | "i"
<digit> ::= "0" | "1" | "2" | "3" | "4"
```

Comment: Added some sidenotes on the unrelated changes to the grammar/AST, including notes on correctness. I'm sure that for all these reasons I'd prefer `Term = variant<Name, Literal>` over your struct approach, because it's just so much more work and more error-prone that last way.

Comment: Thanks for this. My other concern is the inheritance from string class. I thought was bad to do that.

Comment: Yeah, it's questionable to inherit from types not designed for it, so if you want to argue it's a short-hand for a better handwritten ADT, then yeah. The point is having the ADT though.