# How to skip line/block/nested-block comments in Boost.Spirit?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

When parsing a language using Boost.Spirit, how can I ensure that I skip

```
// line comments

/* block
   comments */ and

/* /* nested
   block */ comments */
```

when reading in the code? At the moment, I just do a `phrase_parse` into a predefined `qi::grammar`. I guess what I need is some sort of skipping lexer, right?

Comment: Yep. Confix parser might come handy. Here's an example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/spirit/repository/example/qi/confix.cpp

Answer (score 7):

No lexers required.

Here's a sample grammar that implements it: [Cross-platform way to get line number of an INI file where given option was found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8358975/cross-platform-way-to-get-line-number-of-an-ini-file-where-given-option-was-foun/8365427#8365427), but regardless you can use a skipper like this:

```
using Skipper = qi::rule<Iterator>;

Skipper block_comment, single_line_comment, skipper;

single_line_comment = "//" >> *(char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
block_comment = "/*" >> *(block_comment | char_ - "*/") > "*/";

skipper = single_line_comment | block_comment;
```

Of course if white-space is also skippable, use

```
skipper = space | single_line_comment | block_comment;
```

This supports nested block-comments, throwing `qi::expectation_failure<>` if there is a missing `*/`.

Note that it specifically doesn't support block comments starting in a single-line-comment.

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0081642f447f926)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using Iterator = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    using Skipper  = qi::rule<Iterator>;

    Skipper block_comment, single_line_comment, skipper;

    {
        using namespace qi;
        single_line_comment = "//" >> *(char_ - eol) >> (eol|eoi);
        block_comment       = ("/*" >> *(block_comment | char_ - "*/")) > "*/";

        skipper             = space | single_line_comment | block_comment;
    }

    Iterator f(std::cin >> std::noskipws), l;

    std::vector<int> data;
    bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, *qi::int_, skipper, data);
    if (ok) {
        std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout << "Parsed ", " "));
        std::cout << "\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
    }

    if (f!=l) {
        std::cout << "Remaining unparsed: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Parsed 123 456 567 901
```

Given the input

```
123 // line comments 234

/* block 345
   comments */ 456

567

/* 678 /* nested
   789 block */ comments 890 */

901
```

Comment: Added a demo [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0081642f447f926)

Comment: For reference, this is the same question in x3 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512152/skippers-in-boost-spirit-x3 .