# Why does my component compile as a container but spirit::x3::int_parser does not?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-x3

I have been working on a better understanding of compile time code especially where spirit::x3 is concerned. I have a class `my_uuid` and it is working fine compiled with x3::rule. But as `Iterator` is declared outside of the scope, it is only good for `std::string::iterator`. So I thought I'd just create a component written like `x3::int_parser`. And as far as I can see, it has exactly the same signature. I've tried putting it in the `x3` namespace and including right after the `..\x3\numeric\int.hpp' header thinking there is some good reason, but it evades me.

If I set a break point in my uuid_parser and the int_parser I can see that the int_parser is left alone, called right from the parser sequence. But my parser is wrapped as if it were a container. If I uncomment the parser at line 40, the compiler starts looking for the likes of `insert`. So, that is even more confusing, why doesn't it compile with the need of `insert` or `move` if I leave it as the last component in the sequence?

I seem to be missing something very fundamental here. My question is not how to fix this but what am I missing. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct uuid_parser : x3::parser<uuid_parser> {
    typedef boost::uuids::uuid attribute_type;
    static bool const has_attribute = true;
    static bool const handles_container = false;

    template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context const& context, x3::unused_type, Attribute& uuid) const {
        boost::iterator_range<Iterator> rng;
        auto ret = x3::parse(first, last, x3::raw[*x3::char_("0-9a-fA-F-")], rng);
        try {
            uuid = boost::uuids::string_generator()(rng.begin(), rng.end());
        }
        catch (std::exception& e) {
            boost::ignore_unused(e);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
const uuid_parser uuid_ = {};

int main() {
    std::string uuid_str(R"(    id(78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb
    id(9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15
    id(bad-9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15
)");
    auto first(uuid_str.begin());
    std::vector<boost::uuids::uuid> attr;
    x3::phrase_parse(first, uuid_str.end(), *(x3::lit("id(") >> uuid_), x3::space, attr);
    //x3::phrase_parse(first, uuid_str.end(), *(x3::lit("uid(") >> uuid_ >> ')'), x3::space, attr);
    for (auto& item : attr)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;

    std::string int_str(" x(1) x(2) x(3)"); auto ibegin(int_str.begin());
    std::vector<int> int_vect;
    x3::phrase_parse(ibegin, int_str.end(), *(x3::lit("x(") >> x3::int_ >> ')'), x3::space, int_vect);
    for (auto& item : int_vect)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion is that `uuids::uuid` looks like a container. You can observe this by adding:

```
template <> struct x3::traits::detail::is_container_impl<boost::uuids::uuid> {
    using type = std::false_type;
};
```

### [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/712218f3a0cf6519)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

struct uuid_parser : x3::parser<uuid_parser> {
    using attribute_type = boost::uuids::uuid;
    static bool const has_attribute = true;
    static bool const handles_container = false;

    template <typename Iterator, typename Context, typename Attribute>
    bool parse(Iterator& first, Iterator const& last, Context const& context,
               x3::unused_type, Attribute& uuid) const
    {
        try {
            boost::iterator_range<Iterator> rng;
            auto ret = x3::parse(first, last, x3::raw[*(x3::xdigit | '-')], rng);
            if (ret)
                uuid = boost::uuids::string_generator()(rng.begin(), rng.end());
            return true;
        } catch (std::exception const&) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

template <> struct x3::traits::detail::is_container_impl<boost::uuids::uuid> {
    using type = std::false_type;
};

int main() {
    const uuid_parser uuid_ = {};
    std::string uuid_str(R"(    uid(78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb)
        uid(9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15)
        uid(bad-9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15)
    )");

    std::vector<boost::uuids::uuid> vec;
    x3::phrase_parse(uuid_str.begin(), uuid_str.end(), *("uid(" >> uuid_ >> ")"), x3::space, vec);
    for (auto const& item : vec)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb
9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15
```

### Add Some Debuggability

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/15dcae8ba1880bd4)**

```
auto u = x3::rule<struct _u, boost::uuids::uuid>{"u"} = uuid_;
auto r = x3::rule<struct _r, boost::uuids::uuid>{"r"} = "uid(" >> u >> ")";
x3::phrase_parse(uuid_str.begin(), uuid_str.end(), *r, x3::space, vec);
```

Prints

```
<r>
  <try>    uid(78461bab-6d7</try>
  <u>
    <try>78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a</try>
    <success>)\n        uid(9350cf</success>
    <attributes>78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb</attributes>
  </u>
  <success>\n        uid(9350cf3</success>
  <attributes>78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb</attributes>
</r>
<r>
  <try>\n        uid(9350cf3</try>
  <u>
    <try>9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8</try>
    <success>)\n        uid(bad-93</success>
    <attributes>9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15</attributes>
  </u>
  <success>\n        uid(bad-935</success>
  <attributes>9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15</attributes>
</r>
<r>
  <try>\n        uid(bad-935</try>
  <u>
    <try>bad-9350cf32-7fe5-40</try>
    <fail/>
  </u>
  <fail/>
</r>
78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb
9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15
```

### Simplify

In fact, as you can see you don't **need** to use `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE`, separating instantiation from declaration at all:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6106bde9d6bababe)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

#include <boost/lexical_cast/try_lexical_convert.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

template <> struct x3::traits::detail::is_container_impl<boost::uuids::uuid> {
    using type = std::false_type;
};

namespace Parser {
    template <typename T> static inline auto as(auto p) {
        return x3::rule<struct _, T>{"as"} = p;
    }

    static inline auto const to_uuid = [](auto& ctx) {
        auto r = _attr(ctx);
        _pass(ctx) = boost::conversion::try_lexical_convert<boost::uuids::uuid>(
            std::string_view{r.begin(), r.end()}, _val(ctx));
    };

    static inline auto const uuid_ =
        as<boost::uuids::uuid>(x3::raw[*(x3::xdigit | '-')][to_uuid]);
} // namespace Parser

int main() {
    std::string uuid_str(R"(    uid(78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb)
        uid(9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15)
        uid(bad-9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15)
    )");

    std::vector<boost::uuids::uuid> vec;
    x3::phrase_parse(uuid_str.begin(), uuid_str.end(), *("uid(" >> Parser::uuid_ >> ")"), x3::space, vec);
    for (auto const& item : vec)
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
78461bab-6d7c-48bc-a79a-b716d1ab97cb
9350cf32-7fe5-40d2-8a0d-c7f7562d7a15
```

### Also, Besides...

You said "Iterator" was hardcoded. In fact, it is. But realize that's used only for explicit template specialization. Nothing prevents you from specializing for several iterator types!

See e.g. [You could workaround by manufacturing a correct context type and instantiate that (as well)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66036568/mixing-non-terminal-rules-from-separeted-translation-unit/66036665#:%7E:text=You%20could%20workaround%20by%20manufacturing%20a%20correct%20context%20type%20and%20instantiate%20that%20(as%20well))

- [Skippers in Boost.Spirit.X3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512152/skippers-in-boost-spirit-x3)
- [Boost Spirit x3 not compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57262850/boost-spirit-x3-not-compiling/57298876#57298876)
- and probably some more in https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a85371%20BOOST_SPIRIT_INSTANTIATE

Comment: As complete sidenote: protect against runaway input/DoS and whitespace inside the literals: `x3::raw[x3::lexeme[x3::repeat(32, 36)[x3::xdigit | '-']]]`.

Comment: Thanks sehe, always the obvious! And now I see it in `container_traits.hpp` line 35, all the criteria was met, so you specialized it away. Good point about `x3::lexeme, x3::repeat`, I'll keep that in mind from here. I do have your `as<>` in my tool box, I also have an `as_error<>` to tie `on_error` in when applicable. That `try_lexical_convert` is new for me, homework! I always seem to learn something new from your posts.

Comment: Nice. I’d call that ‘with_error’ probably, but I get the idea.