# Save token position

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I need to save parsed token position along with token. This is simplified sample code.

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

    struct double_w_pos
    {
        double_w_pos() : d(-1.0), pos(0) {}
        double_w_pos(double d, size_t p) : d(d), pos(p) {}
        double d;
        size_t pos;
    };

    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector<double_w_pos>& v)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::phrase_parse;
        using qi::_1;
        using ascii::space;
        using phoenix::at_c;
        using phoenix::push_back;

        bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,
            (
                double_[push_back(phoenix::ref(v), phoenix::construct<double_w_pos>(qi::_1, 0))] % ','
            )
            ,
            space);

        if (first != last)
            return false;
        return r;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<client::double_w_pos> v;
    std::string str = "2.0, 3.45, 5.67, 2.08";

    client::parse_numbers(str.begin(), str.end(), v);

    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i.d << " at " << i.pos << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You can run it live on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a367b7a795107a3) 
Now 0 is saved as token position. How can i get actual parsing position. It need not to be size_t. It can be iterator or anything, what can be used to identify position in text, at which token was found.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I didn't manage to get position as size_t directly from parsing, but i managed to get iterator position. It is not exactly what i need, but it is better than nothing.
Here is the code

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_statement.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_iter_pos.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

namespace client
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;
    namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

    struct double_w_pos
    {
        double_w_pos(double d, std::string::iterator p) : d(d), pos(p) {}
        double d;
        std::string::iterator pos;
    };


    template <typename Iterator>
    bool parse_numbers(Iterator first, Iterator last, std::vector<double_w_pos>& v)
    {
        using qi::double_;
        using qi::phrase_parse;
        using qi::_1;
        using ascii::space;
        using phoenix::at_c;
        using phoenix::push_back;
        using phoenix::begin;
        using boost::spirit::repository::qi::iter_pos;

        bool r = phrase_parse(first, last,
            (
               (iter_pos >> qi::double_)[push_back(phoenix::ref(v), phoenix::construct<double_w_pos>(qi::_2,  qi::_1))] % ","
            )
            ,
            space);

        if (first != last)
            return false;
        return r;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<client::double_w_pos> v;
    std::string str = "2.0, 3.45, 5.67, 2.08";

    client::parse_numbers(str.begin(), str.end(), v);

    for(auto i : v)
        std::cout << i.d << " at " << std::distance(str.begin(), i.pos) << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6b04c6d094b3d4b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following guides:

- [storing line numbers of expressions with boost.spirit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130099/storing-line-numbers-of-expressions-with-boost-spirit-2/10663786#10663786)
- [boost spirit parse with the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144509/boost-spirit-parse-with-the-source/19145704#19145704)

But by far my preferred method (least intrusive) uses `on_success` which is, outside of a sample that uses it, sadly under-documented:

- [boost::spirit access position iterator from semantic actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612657/boostspirit-access-position-iterator-from-semantic-actions/19613827#19613827)